# Configure ASP.NET Web API application as a Virtual Directory under ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, virtual-directory

Due to various engineering requirements, I need to develop a new ASP.NET Web API application (named as  BarApp) within the same Application domain of an existing application (named as FooApp).

I would like to configure an ASP.NET Web API application (BarApp) as a virtual directory under an existing ASP.NET MVC application (FooApp) on IIS 8.5. Though many many posts talked about how to configure a virtual directory, none of them work.

Here is the configuration snippet

```
        <site name="FooApp" id="3" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="FooApp">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\FooApp" />
                <virtualDirectory path="/Bar" physicalPath="E:\BarApp" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:34566:" sslFlags="0" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

Here is the website structure:

```
-FooApp
|
|--Bin
|--View
|--Bar (as a virtual directory)
    |
    |--Bin
    |--View
```

In the Foo App, I configured the routing: add an ingore route for all path with Bar

```
--RouteConfig.cs
  namespace FooApp
  {
       public class RouteConfig
       {
          public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
         {
             routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
             routes.IgnoreRoute("{*path}", new { path = @"Bar\/(.*)" });

             routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
             );
         }
   }
}
```

--WebApiConfig, keep the automatically generated one.

```
 namespace FooApp
 {
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
          }
     }
}
```

In the BarApp, the routing configure is modified as:

```
--RouteConfig.cs
namespace BarApp
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "Bar/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
         }
     }
}

--WebApiConfig
namespace BarApp
{
   public static class WebApiConfig
   {
       public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
      {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "Bar/api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
      }
   }
}
```

However, the above configuration does not work, and the ignore route seems not taken into effect.
Failed to access page of Bar: https://mywebsite.test.com:4433/Bar/
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Failed to access Web API of Bar: https://mywebsite.test.com:4433/Bar/api/values 
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

the  Web API library is 2.2.1

Answer (score 8):

I think the problem with your approach is trying to host an Asp.Net application inside a Virtual Directory. Rather, you must add a child **Application**:

[image: IIS - Add child application]

Then modify the web.config of the root application to avoid configuration collisions:

[image: Avoid collisions in child's web.config]

Reference: [Disable inheritance in child applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4144263/1454888) and [validateIntegratedModeConfiguration and inheritInChildApplications clash](http://articles.runtings.co.uk/2010/04/solved-iis7-validateintegratedmodeconfi.html).

This way, you will be able to access your child web api without modifying any c# code:

[image: Child web api]

Comment: I had the same issue and got resolved with this approach. Only difference being that the child application had it's own web.config in the same child folder. (Maybe because it's developed in NET 6 where the web.config and appSettings.json are separate)

Answer (score 5):

I haven't setup virtual application using configuration files (only through IIS and publish) but I believe the issue you are having is the understanding of how the route URL is mapped in a virtual application. For the following, let's assume your FooApp has a DNS set to fooapp (`http://fooapp/`).

If you have a Bar virtual application under fooapp, the root of the Bar website will be `http://fooapp/Bar`. If we look at your route definitions (MVC and WebApi):

```
// MVC Route
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "Bar/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

// WebApi Route
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "Bar/api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Both your routes are set to listen to a `Bar` "directory" under the running application. If your WebApi application we published on its own (let's say on localhost), this would be `http://localhost/Bar`. But you are actually under `http://fooapp/Bar` and it will be capturing the request based on that root path which would be `http://fooapp/Bar/Bar` (so  `http://fooapp/Bar/Bar/api/values`, etc..).

As far as ignore routes goes, if there is no controller handling a route on `/Bar` in the `FooApp`, the application will tell IIS that it doesn't know how to treat the request and IIS will then move to other Handlers (static file handlers, and so on). Let's take your request as an example (`https://mywebsite.test.com:4433/Bar/`). Since it's under a virtual application, it will ask the `Bar` application if it can handle a `/` route. Since your route definitions in the Bar application only handles `/Bar/{tokens}`, it will default to the static file handler (which in this case would be the directory browsing) and return a 403 due to configuration.

If you take your second example (`https://mywebsite.test.com:4433/Bar/api/values`), it will ask the Bar application if it can handle `/api/values` which it can't (remember, it can handle `/Bar/api/values`, not `/api/values`). Since your application can't, it will go back to the other handlers and nobody will be able to fulfill the request and return a 404.

Comment: Simon, Thank you very much for the sounding analysis. However, I experiment with the configure: In the Bar App, the MVC route is changed as "url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",", and the Web API route is changed as " routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",". The request for https://mywebsite.test.com:4433/Bar/api/values still returns 404. Note that, Bar App has ValuesController to process the get request for api/values. Do you have any other ideas to find out the reason? Thank you!

Comment: From the tracing logs, I do see GENERAL_CHILD_REQUEST_START event, details are:
SiteId: 6 
RequestURL:https://localhost:4433/Bar/api/values 
RequestVerb:GET 
RecursiveLevel:1 
But GENERAL_CHILD_REQUEST_END event returns 404 error.

Comment: Please someone should call someone at microsoft to solve this problem. Im now having to revert to page methods until I can get this to work

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. solution is simple: in both `MVC` `RouteConfiguration` you need the routes to the child virtual application (here if you have bar under foo, foo needs to know the bar-routes).

For bar app you need the routes documented by Simon!

Kind regards

Tara

Comment: Please provide example.