# Using RouteAttribute and IIS Application gives 404 error

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have created a webAPI project and I would like to start hosting it in IIS.

The method in the controller looks like this:

```
    [TokenAuthentication]
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles=Roles.PING)]
    [Route("~/Ping")]
    public DateTime Ping()
    {
        return DateTime.UtcNow;

    }
```

My WebApiConfig looks like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelAttribute());
        //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        //    name: "DefaultApi",
        //    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
        //    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        //);
    }
}
```

When I run the project via visual studio, and go to the link http://localhost:53722/ping I get an unauthorized response which is what I expect.

When I put the website on IIS in an applicaion with the virtual path "/Account" I get a 404 response and it is trying to use the StaticFile Handler.

Through searching online I have runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests set to true.  I have also found [Configure ASP.NET Web API application as a Virtual Directory under ASP.NET MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109026/configure-asp-net-web-api-application-as-a-virtual-directory-under-asp-net-mvc-a) which seems like the "/Account/" should not be interfering with the route.

I can not put the API at the route directory because I will be running multiple microservices under the same site.

How would I get the route to work using the virtual directory?

Thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 0):

Each site should be running as an Application and not a Virtual Directory (and ideally with each having its own application pool).

Out of the box you would normally go for

```
 [Route("ping")]
```

This would give you a url of `http://blah.com/ping`
If you are running this api in a sub folder/application then it maybe something like `http://blah.com/subapp/ping`

This is all i have...