# How to host non-sitecore website under the same domain where sitecore multi site is hosted? Can anyone help suggesting?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore-mvc

I refereed few links and tried to create a virtual app and but still non-Sitecore app is referring to Sitecore root web.config file.

Comment: Is your non-sitecore site using a sub-domain name of the sitecore site? If yes, you can define that in IIS, pointing the subdomain to a new folder location.

Comment: Yes, i have tried creating sub-domain. but the non-sitecore site is referring to root web.config. My subdomain site has it own web.config. I want to use that. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to look at Application Request Routing: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to setup a child application under Sitecore website in IIS. In this case, if you don't apply inheritance configuration correctly, you'll face the issue when child application uses configuration defined in the parent (Sitecore) web.config. This post should help you with the right configuration: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144117/nested-asp-net-application-within-iis-inheriting-parent-config-values)

Comment: @Vladimir I'm pretty sure your comment answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to setup a child application under Sitecore website in IIS. In this case, if you don't apply inheritance configuration correctly, you'll face the issue when child application uses configuration defined in the parent (Sitecore) web.config. This post should help you with the right configuration: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144117/nested-asp-net-application-within-iis-inheriting-parent-config-values)

Comment: Thank you Vladimir.

Comment: @dev, if this answer works for you, could you mark it as accepted, please? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)